# My cheesecake is runny, how do i fix it?

Tags: cheesecake, aluminum-foil

I made a no bake cheesecake without gelatin. And instead of the parchment paper, I used aluminium foil to cover the container. Now, the dish has been in the freezer for two days and the cake is still runny. How can I insure that the cake is not runny?

Comment: Definite duplicate

Comment: @GeorgeM In this case it seems to be the same cheesecake, with the same problem and posted by the same poster. Is that close enough?

Comment: When you say 'without gelatin', are you saying that it's a recipe that didn't use gelatin, or that you missed adding it?